# MQTT Topic rewritten 1

Tags: mqtt

We are using the MQTT protocol for sending sensor data. I heard like there is feature called topic rewritten in MQTT broker. Anyone knows what is the use of topic rewritten in MQTT.

Comment: MQTT is a protocol with many different implementations. The feature of rewriting a topic is not something defined in the MQTT protocol; it is an implementation-specific feature. its purpose is to republish messages published on one topic, to a different topic.

Comment: **Thanks** for good explaination

Comment: Do you know which brokers have support for it?

Comment: Yes, IBM watson cloud